# How do I take a screenshot of the keyboard viewer with modifiers (e.g. Alt Gr, Shift)?

Tags: keyboard, screen-capture

I am used to working on a US/CA English keyboard, but I'm currently based overseas and the keyboard that my workplace got for me has a completely different layout (ISO European). It's especially difficult for me to remember where the symbols are that are being modified by the `Alt Gr` and `Shift` keys, so I thought I'd make a screenshot of the OS X keyboard viewer. I know that I can take a picture of an application window with the `Apple + Shift + 4 + Space Bar` shortcut, but I can't seem to get the modifier key to "stick" so that I can take a screenshot of the keyboard layout with the modifier. How do I do this?

Comment: Maybe a Timed Screen Capture with Grab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use Applications/Utilities/Grab.app for this kind of thing, it offers more kinds of capture including timed.

Comment: Worked perfectly. I was able to capture the window with the modifer key pressed, without having to used timed capture. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, this helped me too. Whenever I pressed the command key, the keyboard viewer would revert to qwerty layout, so I couldn't capture the actual layout using Cmd+Shift+3, 4, or whatever. Using Grab instead solved  the problem.