# How to magnify OS X keyboard viewer?

Tags: macos, keyboard

The keyboard viewer is so tiny, but it does not seem to be resizable (other than full screen, which hides what I want to type into!).

Taking a screen image of it is [awkward at best](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/247523/how-do-i-take-a-screenshot-of-the-keyboard-viewer-with-modifiers-e-g-alt-gr-s) and when the result is magnified, not only does clarity suffer greatly, but you can't "type" by clicking on the image.  You can of course look at the image and click on the viewer (or just use the real keyboard) but that's not optimal either.

Is there a way to make the actual keyboard viewer fully usable by someone with aging eyes, or must I settle for an irritating workaround?

Comment: What OS X version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to make the Keyboard Viewer bigger by just click/dragging any of the corners.

Comment: Well, not the lower right corner, which worked a few OS version back.  I guess I should try the other corners.  Actually, it does work "BUT" (I edited that detail into your answer)

Comment: Hmmm, my edit disappeared.  Dragging the corners does work.  I foolishly assumed that when Apple took away the resizing cursor that they also took away the ability to resize.  So I hadn't actually tried to resize.

Comment: You can also hit the green maximise button to make the keyboard take up the full width of your display.