# Unrequested disabling of most text input features

Tags: macos, keyboard, input-source, text-input

See also update below.

For some time, I have been using Unicode Hex Input 99% of the time.  Recently, with some assistance [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/381872/adding-popup-menu-to-an-input-method-that-doesnt-support-it) and from the author of [Ukelele](http://belkadan.com/blog/2012/04/Keyboard-Adventures/), I managed to add press-and-hold pop-ups to Unicode Hex Input, which eliminated any need for any other IM or keyboard for European languages.  But a few days ago, possibly with the upgrade to 10.15.4, MacOS has taken to switching me to Apple's default (U.S.) every time I change focus from one app to another or from one Safari tab to another.

**Is it an Apple bug, or is there something new I missed in the release notes?  Is there a simple fix/workaround?**

[Something similar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/255132/65467) happened in 2016, but that fixed itself without my doing anything (as far as I was aware).

UPDATE 1: Furthermore, my list no longer has an input method for Chinese, and cannot find either "Chinese" nor "Mandarin" on the list of languages.  The press-and-hold pop-ups no longer work, and the keyboard viewer & character palette are also no longer available (show keyboard & emoji viewers in menu bar is unchecked and turning it on doesn't get saved).

UPDATE 2: Following Tom's suggestion, installing the 10.15.4 Catalina combo restored the availability of Chinese, but removed all input methods but Turkish and Greek, which prevented typing a login password!  Had to select "other" and reinstall them on the login screen, but had to do it twice before it would stick.  And then trying to do press-and-hold would disable the keyboard completely.  I could restore it, though, by changing keyboards.  Hold any key down too long, even one with no press-and-hold options defined, would make all keys no longer functional until a different keyboard is selected with the mouse.

UPDATE 3: Today (9 April 2020) Apple released a minor update (did not change version number) which fixed both press-and-hold problems I described in update 2!

Comment: Sure sounds like botched update.  Try downloading the Combo update for 15.4 and installing that manually.

Comment: Took me a while to find it, but I’ll try that as soon as my backup finishes.

Comment: @TomGewecke, given my updates, perhaps you'd like to turn your comment into an answer?